# Using a "population" consisting of probabilities to predict accuracy of sample

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

Since I'm not sure if the title explains my question well enough I've come up with an example myself:

Let's say I live in a country where every citizen goes to work everyday and every citizen has the choice to go by bus or by train (every citizen makes this choice everyday again - there are almost no citizens who always go by train and never by bus, and vice-versa).

I've done a lot of sampling and I have data on one million citizens about their behaviour in the past 1000 days. So, I calculate the "probability" per citizen of going by train on a single day. I can also calculate the average of those calculated probabilities of all citizens, let's say the average probability of a citizen going by train is 0.27. I figured that most citizens have tendencies around this number (most citizens have an individual probability between 0.22 and 0.32 of going by train for example).

Now, I started sampling an unknown person (but known to be living in the same country) and after asking him 10 consecutive days whether he went by train or by bus, I know that this person went to his work by train 4 times, and by bus 6 times.

My final question: how can I use my (accurate) data on one million citizens to approximate this person's probability of going by train?

I know that if I do the calculation the other way around, so, calculate the probability of this event occurring given the fact that I know this person's REAL probability is 0.4 this results in: 0.4^4 * 0.6^6 * 10C4 = ~25%. I could calculate this probability for all possible probabilities between 0.00 and 1.00 (so, 0%-100% without any numbers in between) and sum them all, which sums to about 910%. I could set this to 100% (dividing by 9.1) and set all other percentages accordingly (dividing everything by 9.1 - so, our 25% becomes ~2.75%) and come up with a weighted sum: 2.75% * 0.4 + X% * 0.41 etc., but this must be wrong since I'm not taking my accurate samples of the population into account.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

These are two different probability distributions.

Using all the data for the country, you are calculating the probability that a citizen, whom you have picked randomly from all the citizens, will take the train .

Using the data for one particular citizen, you end up with the probability that 
 that citizen will take the train.

In both cases the maximum likelihood estimator for the probability of taking the train is $$ \hat{p} = \frac{\sum^N_{i=1}x_i}{\sum^N_{i=1}n_i} $$ where $N$ is the total number of all the samples, $x_i$ is the amount of times the train was taken in sample $i$ and $n_i$ is the sample size of sample $i$.

Let's say you have the data for Sarah and Bob, the only two citizens in the country. The data shows Sarah has taken the train $4$ times out of $10$ and Bob has taken the train $6$ times out of $10$.

Then \begin{align*} \hat{p_1} &= P(\text{Sarah takes the train}) = 0.4 \\  \hat{p_2} &= P(\text{Bob takes the train}) = 0.6 \end{align*}
but
$$ \hat{p} = P(\text{Citizen takes the train}) =  P(\text{Picking Sarah})P(\text{Sarah takes the train}) + P(\text{Picking Bob})P(\text{Bob takes the train}) = 0.5\times0.4 + 0.5\times0.6 = 0.5  $$
And this just simplifies to the estimator given earlier.

Comment: I don't get it completely..I made up this table to clarify: http://i66.tinypic.com/2iuf0vb.jpg

The table contains data of 2219 citizens who have each been observed 1000 times. The probability of taking the train is different for each citizen (0.08-0.55 in this example). Train has been taken 660,980 times out of 2,219,000 times.

How can I use this distribution when estimating another citizen's *overall* probability given I already know this person went by train 4 out of 10 times. So, using all the information, how can I predict the  probability of this person going by train the 11th time?

Comment: Since I'm not sure if you're able to open the picture with the table, I re-upped it here: https://imgur.com/a/A4mLh

Comment: @DamiaanReijnaers i have added an example to the answer

Comment: Thanks again, your help is really appreciated! Doesn't the fact that I already have data on citizen influence the probability? If I have no data at all on the citizen, I understand the probability is 0.5 in your example. But after observing the citizen, I can rely more on my observations.

If I have 0 times observed the citizen, I should 100% take the population into account - probability will be 0.5

If I have 1000 times observed the citizen, I should ~0% take the population into account - probability will be as measured

But, how to weigh?

Comment: In the real world I'm trying to predict someone's behavior. At first, not knowing this person, I will look at my big data. What does the average person do?

But the more I observe this person, the more accurate my predictions will become (using my data on this particular person) and the less I need to look at the big data file (the "population").

After observing the person for some period of time, I already have "an idea" what kind of person this is. So, -back to the example- if the person went 8 out of 10 times by train, this person is already much less likely to be in the average group.

Comment: @DamiaanReijnaers The data you have on that 1 citizen should form part of the big data set and therefore would influence the overall probability. The big data set is the best source for estimating the overall probability, the data for 1 citizen only gives you information on that 1 citizen. You could collect the data for a particular demographic (e.g all males over 20) which would be more useful.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot strider.

But what if I want to predict ONLY this one citizen's behavior (after having observed this person for a small period of time)?

Since there are just two outcomes, let's say 100 observations are accurate enough. So, if I found that after 100 observations this citizen goes by train about 40% of the time, I'm going with this statistic since it's just more and more likely this is just a person who likes to go by train 40% of all days.

So, having observed citizen X times, I want to predict as accurately as possible the (X+1)th time I observe citizen.

Comment: For example: If I observed a person just three times, and he went to work all three times by train, so the result of my sample is 100%. But, knowing that it is very unlikely that a citizen goes to work 100% by train and 0% by bus, I quickly disregard this statistic (in my table there are by far no people who have this statistic). But, the fact that this person went this three times in row by train makes me feel that there is a higher chance that this person is on the higher end (going more by train than average) than on the lower end.

Comment: @DamiaanReijnaers As long as the assumption holds that events are independent, then the probability that this citizen will take the train on any trial is just 0.4, or whatever you have calculated as an estimate for that citizen for the parameter at that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65412/discussion-between-strider-and-damiaan-reijnaers).

Comment: But I guess they are not totally independent. This person doesn't wake up every morning and throws a dice. This person has a preference for taking the train some percentage of the time, from the moment he was born. A percentage he knows and I want to predict using my knowledge about people's tendencies in general and my sample on this person that is getting more and more accurate over time.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found my answer, which -looking back- was obvious: Bayesian probability. More specificially: posterior distributions.

Not solving the matter totally but hinting in the right direction for any people in the future looking for the same answer:

To calculate whether a citizen goes by train 25% of the time **given the fact** that we observed the citizen going 4 times by train out of 10 times, we can write it as:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) * P(A)}{P(B)}$

where P(A) = citizen goes by train 25% of the time
and P(B) =  citizen is observed to go 4 out of 10 times by train